# Assuming $d+1 <= log_2(n)$, how to show $d - 1 > log_2(n/8)$?

Tags: logarithms

Also we know $d = log_2(n/2)$ rounded down to its nearest integer.

Add (-2) to each side
$$d-1 <= log_2(n) - 2$$
$$d-1 <= log_2(n) - log_2(4)$$
$$d-1 <= log_2(n/4)$$

This is as far as I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take any real number $x$ and round down to the nearest integer, the result is greater than $x-1$.  So
$$d>\log_2\Bigl(\frac n2\Bigr)-1=\log_2n-2$$
and
$$d-1>\log_2n-3=\log_2\Bigl(\frac n8\Bigr)\ .$$

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessarily true. For example, if $d=1$ and $n=1024$, then
$$d+1=2\le 10=\log_2(n) $$
yet
$$ d-1=0 \not > 7 = \log_2(n/8) $$

Comment: OK, I've left out one piece of information. $d = log_2(n/2)$ rounded down to nearest integer.

Comment: @kptlronyttcna: That's pretty critical.

Comment: $d + 1 <= log_2(n)$ was actually derived from the missing info. I didn't noticed its importance after your answer. Sorry.